# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex - Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-multidex

Before asked the question I tried many solutions, but none of them works see below my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'}
```

So when I trie to run app throw Android studio 3.0.1 I get error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

And the defaultConfig

```
{
    applicationId "fr.xxxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```